# php foreach uploaded file define variable

Tags: php, forms, variables, file-upload, foreach

Not a problem to upload multiple files and save them. But I would like to take those uploaded files and display them on the same page

```
$ebtitle2 = substr(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "", $ebtitle), 0, 8);
$upload_folder = '../ebay/images/'. $Date.'-'.$ebtitle2."/";
mkdir("$upload_folder");
$z = 0;
foreach ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    $tmp_name = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    $uname = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"][$key];
    $folderandname = $upload_folder.$z.$ebtitle2.$uname;
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $folderandname);
    $z++;
    }
}
```

Would like to take these image locations and define them so they can be displayed further on down the page.

```
$x = $z;
while($z > 0) {
    $imgURL['$z'] = $folderandname[];
    $z -1;
}
```

Then later on down the script:

```
<?php while($x > 0) { ?>
<img src='<?php $imageURL[]; ?>'>
<?php $x -1;} ?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You know the file name and where they are saved. Why can't you put them into your HTML like any other image?

Comment: If you want to display the images in the same script execution, it will need to be as `<img src='the new img'>` tags.

Comment: I should clarify.... Yes, in the same script execution... `<img src="<? $folderandname['0']; ?>"> Rinse, repeat. So if there were 3 files uploaded there could be 5 variables 1 for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Trial and error...

```
$ebtitle2 = substr(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "", $ebtitle), 0, 8);
$upload_folder = '../ebay/images/'. $Date.'-'.$ebtitle2."/";
mkdir("$upload_folder");
$z = 0;
foreach ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $uname = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"][$key];
        $folderandname = $upload_folder.$z.$ebtitle2.$uname;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $folderandname);
        $imgURL[] = $Date.'-'.$ebtitle2."/".$z.$ebtitle2.$uname;
        $z++;
    }
}

$x = 0;
while($z > 0) {
    echo "<img src='https://itdsi.com/ebay/images/".$imgURL[$x]."'>";
    $z--;
    $x++;
}
```